# Remove multiple matching columns from multiple character string

Tags: r, pattern-matching, dplyr

I have a dataframe of over 200 variables, many of which end with a code for a given species. I want to eliminate any columns that contain one of several codes, contained in a separate vector of character strings. How can I remove these multiple columns matching the multiple codes at the same time? The column names don't match the code values exactly, but contain the codes at the end of the column name. For example:

```
 "rev230" "rev3360" "rev3508"
```

Manually, I've done this (using the `dplyr` package):

```
sub = select(df, -contains("3781"), -contains("3751"), -contains("1408"), 
    -contains("1409"), -contains("4469"), -contains("1789"), -contains("4559"), 
    -contains("1453"),-contains("8"), -contains("3508"), -contains("4656"), 
    -contains("5131"), -contains("9999"))
```

This gets me what I want (eliminating all columns that contain data on the species matching these codes), but obviously this is very tedious. 
I'd like something more like:

```
sub = select(df, -contains(species$codes))
# I realize this isn't the right syntax
```

I tried a loop to remove individual columns, using something like this:

```
foreach(i=1:length(species$codes), .combine=rbind)%do%
select(df, -contains(species$codes[i]))
```

but that didn't work either. Thanks in advance!

reproducible example:
Species codes (contained in a character vector):

```
 dput(species)
    c("3754", "3755", "3758", "3764", "3765", "3771", "3772", "3782", 
    "3761", "3762", "3763", "3767", "3768", "1790", "1412", "1413", 
    "1416", "1422", "1423", "1424", "1425", "1426", "1410", "1411", 
    "1414", "1415", "1420", "3770", "4740", "4470", "4472", "4474", 
    "4476", "4479", "4480", "1812", "1815", "1799", "4560", "3810", 
    "1440", "1441", "3302", "3295", "3560", "3360", "1940", "3840", 
    "570", "1050", "4710", "230")
```

Here are the first 10 rows of the data, with only columns for species data

```
dput(logsub)
structure(list(lbs3781 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 708), lbs3764 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3765 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 708), lbs3758 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3755 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3782 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), lbs3751 = c(0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 18, 0), lbs3761 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0), lbs3762 = c(0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 0), lbs3763 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3767 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3768 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), lbs3754 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3771 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3772 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), lbs1790 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0), lbs1409 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 86), lbs1411 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), lbs1414 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs1415 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 86), lbs4740 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), lbs1420 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3770 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs1408 = c(2508, 785, 57, 0, 132, 
5003, 18, 104, 636, 0), lbs1412 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), lbs1413 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs1416 = c(2331, 
654, 57, 0, 81, 4284, 15, 104, 120, 0), lbs1422 = c(177, 0, 0, 
0, 51, 719, 3, 0, 0, 0), lbs1423 = c(0, 131, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
502, 0), lbs1424 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0), lbs1425 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs1426 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), lbs1410 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs4469 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs4470 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), lbs4472 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    lbs4474 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs4476 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), lbs4479 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), lbs4480 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs1789 = c(0, 0, 0, 863, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 98), lbs1812 = c(0, 0, 0, 863, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27), lbs1815 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 71), lbs1799 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), lbs4559 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12), 
    lbs4560 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12), lbs3810 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), lbs1453 = c(0, 0, 5, 
    0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 15, 235), lbs1440 = c(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 21, 
    0, 15, 0), lbs1441 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3560 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3302 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 235), lbs3295 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    lbs0008 = c(0, 97, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs1940 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3840 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), lbs1050 = c(0, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    lbs4710 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs570 = c(0, 
    97, 68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs230 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3360 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs3508 = c(0, 
    0, 5043, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs4656 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lbs9999 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    rev3781 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1688.144979), rev3764 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev3765 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1688.144979), rev3758 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), rev3755 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev3782 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev3751 = c(0, 0, 7.063636364, 
    0, 0, 0, 33.44605263, 0, 32.53608247, 0), rev3761 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27.34105263, 0, 0, 0), rev3762 = c(0, 0, 7.063636364, 
    0, 0, 0, 6.105, 0, 0, 0), rev3763 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), rev3767 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev3768 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev3754 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), rev3771 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev3772 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev1790 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 32.53608247, 0), rev1409 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 260.0068669), rev1411 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ), rev1414 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev1415 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 260.0068669), rev4740 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev1420 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), rev3770 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev1408 = c(6349.327025, 
    2014.2837, 142.8362084, 0, 339.5618788, 13265.98305, 41.94345809, 
    235.6862428, 1835.487932, 0), rev1412 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev1413 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    rev1416 = c(5841.249152, 1623.155767, 142.8362084, 0, 194.2835976, 
    11101.38378, 33.99320809, 235.6862428, 299.2968186, 0), rev1422 = c(508.0778723, 
    0, 0, 0, 145.2782813, 2164.599274, 7.95025, 0, 0, 0), rev1423 = c(0, 
    391.1279328, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1494.676782, 0), rev1424 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 41.51433134, 0), rev1425 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev1426 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), rev1410 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev4469 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev4470 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), rev4472 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev4474 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev4476 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), rev4479 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), rev4480 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev1789 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 963.8520574, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 95.34540063), rev1812 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 963.8520574, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30.02711217), rev1815 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65.31828847), rev1799 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev4559 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 12.94965112), rev4560 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12.94965112
    ), rev3810 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev1453 = c(0, 
    0, 3.505617978, 0, 0, 0, 13.9460241, 0, 10.93726937, 225.778089
    ), rev1440 = c(0, 0, 3.505617978, 0, 0, 0, 13.9460241, 0, 
    10.93726937, 0), rev1441 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ), rev3560 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev3302 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 225.778089), rev3295 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev0008 = c(0, 180.3441341, 169.7750491, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev1940 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), rev3840 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev1050 = c(0, 
    0, 48.71428571, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev4710 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev570 = c(0, 180.3441341, 121.0607634, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev230 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), rev3360 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev3508 = c(0, 
    0, 2620.957866, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev4656 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rev9999 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0)), .Names = c("lbs3781", "lbs3764", "lbs3765", "lbs3758", 
"lbs3755", "lbs3782", "lbs3751", "lbs3761", "lbs3762", "lbs3763", 
"lbs3767", "lbs3768", "lbs3754", "lbs3771", "lbs3772", "lbs1790", 
"lbs1409", "lbs1411", "lbs1414", "lbs1415", "lbs4740", "lbs1420", 
"lbs3770", "lbs1408", "lbs1412", "lbs1413", "lbs1416", "lbs1422", 
"lbs1423", "lbs1424", "lbs1425", "lbs1426", "lbs1410", "lbs4469", 
"lbs4470", "lbs4472", "lbs4474", "lbs4476", "lbs4479", "lbs4480", 
"lbs1789", "lbs1812", "lbs1815", "lbs1799", "lbs4559", "lbs4560", 
"lbs3810", "lbs1453", "lbs1440", "lbs1441", "lbs3560", "lbs3302", 
"lbs3295", "lbs0008", "lbs1940", "lbs3840", "lbs1050", "lbs4710", 
"lbs570", "lbs230", "lbs3360", "lbs3508", "lbs4656", "lbs9999", 
"rev3781", "rev3764", "rev3765", "rev3758", "rev3755", "rev3782", 
"rev3751", "rev3761", "rev3762", "rev3763", "rev3767", "rev3768", 
"rev3754", "rev3771", "rev3772", "rev1790", "rev1409", "rev1411", 
"rev1414", "rev1415", "rev4740", "rev1420", "rev3770", "rev1408", 
"rev1412", "rev1413", "rev1416", "rev1422", "rev1423", "rev1424", 
"rev1425", "rev1426", "rev1410", "rev4469", "rev4470", "rev4472", 
"rev4474", "rev4476", "rev4479", "rev4480", "rev1789", "rev1812", 
"rev1815", "rev1799", "rev4559", "rev4560", "rev3810", "rev1453", 
"rev1440", "rev1441", "rev3560", "rev3302", "rev3295", "rev0008", 
"rev1940", "rev3840", "rev1050", "rev4710", "rev570", "rev230", 
"rev3360", "rev3508", "rev4656", "rev9999"), row.names = c(34367L, 
48646L, 48715L, 48717L, 48722L, 48724L, 48743L, 48744L, 48781L, 
48783L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try something like `sub <- logsub[!grepl(paste(species, collapse = "|"), names(logsub))]` (haven't tested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One options is `select_if` with `grepl`, as `grepl` returns a logical vector and you can include multiple patterns you want to match on via `|`.

A simple case where you want to remove two species would look like:

```
select_if(df, !grepl("3781|3751", names(df)) )
```

Aggregate all of your species into the right form for `grepl` via `paste` with `collapse`, and then use this within `grepl`.

```
select_if(df, !grepl(paste(species, collapse = "|"), names(df)) )
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great! I ended up using it as a column selection rather than the select_if function:

Comment: `sub =df[,!grepl(paste(species$code, collapse="|"), names(df))]`